# Using Intel-x86 Atom Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Installed HAXM for linux 64bit and KVM installed successfully.
Hardware supports VT.
VT enabled in bios.
Installed Intel x86 Atom System Images for desired API's.
**Still can't change CPU/abi to Intel x86 using ADV Manager.**

This was working for my previous machine with eclipse Indigo,Now not working with ADT bundle From Developers site 
[ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem with ADT version.
I updated ADT version to latest 22.6 and now it is working properly.
Thanks for advices though.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your AVD, be sure to select the API level for which you have an x86 image installed.  In your screen caps above, you show that you have x86 images installed for API level 15 and API level 10.  If you are creating an AVD with API level 19, you will not be able to select the x86 image since it is not installed.

Comment: Actually I know I need to seletct API level for one I downloaded x86 image.As mentioned in my question I did use x86 previously.But now problem is AVD not allowing me to change to Intelx86 image even for API 15 and 10.
Probably it is a bug for some issue with ADT bundle?

Comment: Probably my eclipse or Android SDK missing some root access or something.I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The AVD manager uses a combination of the device definitions and installed platform images.  If you are using one of the standard device definitions it should work ok for you.  It's possible if you are using your own custom device definition that the tools are getting confused.

Comment: Sorry but it is not helping me.
I am leaving it as it is,its such a headache.
Why android with linux has to be so buggy.

Answer (score 0):

can you check your permissions for your SDK folder ?

`ls -al /home/pankaj/PankajWorkplace/DevelopmentTools/sdk/system-images/android-15/*`

Maybe your AVD Manager doesn't use the right location. If you launch it from eclipse, is eclipse configured to use the Android SDK in /home/pankaj/PankajWorkplace/DevelopmentTools/sdk ? You can change this path from eclipse Window -> preferences -> Android.

Comment: which permissions system-images folder should have to work properly?

Comment: read permission to files and directories for your user is enough

Comment: Well it has read,in fact I added read,write,execute permissions and checked if it is working.
But no luck